# Embed the Facebook "Book Now" feature on website

Tags: html, facebook

I am looking for a way to **embed** the Facebook "**Book Now**" feature onto a website. For those of you who are not familiar it is essentially a plugin that allows visitors to book a service. I am not sure how to accomplish this, whether I use an iframe and hide all contents except the plugin or if there is an easier way.

[image]

Comment: Even if Facebook did not forbid browsers from displaying their pages in (i)frames on different domains via the `X-Frame-Options` header, you would still have no access at all via JS or CSS. And AFAIK they don’t offer any sort of plugin that offers this functionality on its own either. The Page plugin can show a custom CTA button for a page - but I am not sure whether this booking button counts as a _custom_ CTA to begin with; you’d have to check/try.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like I will just end up having to popup the Facebook in a new window and go from there.

Comment: I know this is a very old thread. I'm trying to achieve something similar. But I'm wondering: what's the direct link/URL to the Facebook "Book Now" of a page?

I have a link which looks like: https://fb.com/book/NameOfThePage/

But this works only on mobile. While on desktop version you just see the Home of the page and then you have to click on "Book Now" button. While on mobile you go straight to the booking calendar.

Thank you.